# Will current flow between the loops in this case?

Tags: voltage, current

> Will current flow between the loops through the link BC in this case?

[image]

I think no, because on both sides of the 1 ohm resistance, the potential is the same, so current shouldn't flow as there's no potential difference there. (But is this reason correct?)

But now, what if I remove the 1 ohm resistor? Will current flow now? What will happen in this case? (Assuming everything is ideal) Will the current eventually fall in the loop with the lower potential?  Here, there is a potential difference between B and C, so charge should flow in, right?

[image]

Comment: How would it flow back?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I don't think it can

Comment: Why in the first case do you assert that the potential on each side of the 1ohm resistr is the same? You're correct, but it looks like for the wrong reason. If a current was flowing BC, then there would be a voltage across that resistor, so reasoning about one doesn't help you with the other. Look for other connections between the two loops, and recall where current flows.

Comment: use a pen to draw the current that flows from the negative side to the positive side of the 4V battery. it has to be a loop.  if you cannot draw a loop, then you have a battery that has a resistor connected to one terminal, and maybe a resistor connected to the other terminal, but the two resistors have no connection to each other

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/303613/139766